# Mysql servers is missing

Tags: mysql

I downloaded mySQL from the website 
 
file name (mysql-installer-community-8.0.12.0.msi) 
 
I'm using a 32 bit laptop. When i try to install it the MySQL 
The MySQL servers is not showing? 
[MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B84TZ.png)

Comment: You probably downloaded the wrong installer.

Comment: which one do i download? for a windows 10 32 bit laptop.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have current GA selected. Go into edit filter and allow previously released GA

Comment: which one do i download? for a windows 10 32 bit laptop.

Comment: go with the 5.7 32 bit